# Want to generate random set of coordinates (Java/Swing)

Tags: java

I have a program in Java like this one (https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8a_GameIntro-BouncingBalls.html). It is the object oriented one after Example 2 but with some slightly changes.

I want to generate random coordinates for the balls to spawn. But they are not allowed to intersect each other at spawning moment. The generated coordinates are the top left corner of an rectangle around the circle.

So the coordinates need a minimum distance of 2 * ballRadius.

I only got ether coordinates that have the distance of 2 * ballRadius but then there are only unique coordinates for x and y. So i only got one ball per available y coordinate. 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwwoy.png) There could be a Ball at the red circle but the one left to it "blocks" the y coordinate.

Every other coordinates i get are intersecting each other.

Thats my code so far.

```
    int uniqueXY[][] = new int[ballCount][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < ballCount; i++) {
        int tempx = 0;
        int tempy = 0;
        Boolean foundX = true;
        Boolean foundY = true;
        while(foundX && foundY) {
            tempx = (int) (Math.random() * field.maxX); // generate random number in range of filed
            tempy = (int) (Math.random() * field.maxY);

            for (int j = 0; j < ballCount; j++) { // Here it should check if the number is within the given rules
                if ((uniqueXY[j][0] - (2 * ballRadius) > tempx) || (uniqueXY[j][0] + (2 * ballRadius) < tempx)) {   
                    foundX = false;
                } else {
                    foundX = true;
                    if ((uniqueXY[j][1] - (2 * ballRadius) > tempy) || (uniqueXY[j][1] + (2 * ballRadius) < tempy)) {
                        foundY = false;
                        foundX = false;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        foundY = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        uniqueXY[i][0] = tempx;
        uniqueXY[i][1] = tempy;
```

Comment: You need to calculate distance between center of the new ball and all the previous ones. And you don't calculate distance by comparing separatly Xs and Ys.

Comment: Hmm, yes. You are right. I need to calculate the distance between the centers. That should resolve my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So I have come up with some new Code with the similar problem.

It calculates the distance between every set coordinate and the temporay ones. For the most part it works fine, it just behaves akward if I strees the code and force large numbers of balls.[Example with 400 balls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipXjl.png) Only the balls at the border get forced together.

```
int uniqueXY[][] = new int[ballCount][2];


    for (int k = 0; k < ballCount; k++) {
        Boolean found = true;
        while(found) {

            int tempX = (int) (Math.random() * field.maxX); //create rnd x/y in range of field
            int tempY = (int) (Math.random() * field.maxY);

            if (k == 0) {       // first case gets set, because nothing to compare
                uniqueXY[k][0] = tempX;
                uniqueXY[k][1] = tempY;
                found = false;
                break;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {   //calculates distance between every set coordinate and the temp
                int erg1 = (int) (Math.pow(uniqueXY[j][0] - tempX, 2));
                int erg2 = (int) (Math.pow(uniqueXY[j][1] - tempY, 2));
                int distance = (int) Math.sqrt(erg1 + erg2);
                if (distance < 60) { // if distance between coordinates < 60 temp gets discarded
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
                if (j == k - 1) { // if every set case is checked and distance was always fine, temp gets set
                    uniqueXY[k][0] = tempX;
                    uniqueXY[k][1] = tempY;
                    found = false;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Solved it. My bad. The rnd generated numbers needed more spacing from the borders.